# jQuery sortable not working with floating items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to move one list item from one side to another. However, it doesn't seem to work. I can move the list items from left to right, but not the other way around. The left side has a float: left in the CSS filesheet. If i remove this, everything seems to work. How can i fix this?

Anyone?

Comment: what? u can move the items from left to right?

Comment: Yes... Left to right and right to left... Using Chrome...

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here.

Comment: and you can "stack" the items? like move one to another, both ways? doesn't work here (using chrome and ff)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem only partially has to do with your CSS.  When you float:left the UL, it doesn't render as a block.  The quick fix is to use a standard 'clearfix' paradigm:

```
#newsLayout ul {display:block;overflow:hidden}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using **float: left** in your List1 LI element, use **display: inline-block**.

For further details, there's an example in jQuery's UI documentation which does more or less exactly what you need.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: i know, and i've looked at it, but when i float the left list, it wont "stack up"

Comment: This! Ditch float, always creates problems. Inline-block is your new best friend.